# Can Google Chrome access the file system?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser

I have an external hard drive attached to my (Windows Vista) computer. For some time, I've noticed that when I run Google Chrome, the drive starts whirring, whereas this never happens with Firefox.

I thought browsers couldn't access the file system. Is this possible?

Comment: A better question would be why does Chrome use the *external drive* instead of just the default user data location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browsers absolutely touch the file systems. How else would data be cached and files saved? Browsers *can* touch the file system, however they limit what sites can access through [NPAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Plugins) etc.

Comment: Accepting this answer now in case I can't do so later. Apologies if anyone else answers

Comment: @user52032 — just because there's already one answer doesn't mean there shouldn't be others. That's the whole point of this site. There's not *one* universal answer to every question.

Comment: @slhck It was just that there were 4 votes on SO to close the question and I thought if it was closed I wouldn't be able to accept the answer after that